# How to redirect a page with variable value if condition is true in php?

Tags: php

how to jump a page if condition true and also i want to sent  a variable value to secont page

```
if(isset($_POST['compair']))
{
     $_SESSION['usermail'];
    $answer=$_POST['answer'];
    if ($answer ==  $_SESSION['answer'])
    {
          $mail=$_SESSION['usermail'];(i want to sent "$mail" variable)
          header("Location:resetpass.php?value = $mail "); 

    }
    else
    {
         echo "<script>alert('Please Try again')</script>";

    } 

}
```

please also tell me how to receive this variable on second page.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. Just pay attention to spaces:

```
header("Location: resetpass.php?value=$mail");
exit; // as suggested by "nogad"
```

Also make sure that `resetpass.php` file is in the same directory of current page.

In `resetpass.php` you can get the variable by `$_GET['value']` like:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['value']) ){
    $mail = $_GET['value'];
}
```

Comment: thanks please can you send code for second page i am new in php.

Answer (score 1):

After header("Location : resetpass.php?value=$mail");
         exit(); // i.e quit the current page and go to resetpass.php

Then at resetpass.php collect $mail using the GET method.

if(isset[$_GET['value'])){

$the_mail = $_GET['value'];

}

I am writing from my handy. So apologies for any layout discripancies

Comment: great this is working i tryed last 3 hours to do that . its woring  thanks